# Why has the link from /usr/local/bin/python3 a different path from "which python3"?

Tags: bash, macos, python-3.6, python-3.7

I installed python 3.6 before and installed python 3.7.4 today. When I type `python3` in command, it opens python 3.6, I want to change it to python 3.7.4.

`which python3` shows `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`,

but the link in `/usr/local/bin/` is :
`python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

so is the case of `pip3`. why? ?

How can I change `which python3` to python 3.7.4? I don't want to use `alias`.

I use MacOS 10.14.2

Comment: Can you provide your PATH variable? `echo $PATH`

Comment: This is my PATH:/Users/sky/Documents/software/Montage-master/bin:/usr/share/file/magic/mercurial:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OS uses the PATH environment variable to look for the commands you write into the shell, so if you type `python3` it will go through the directories listed in this PATH and check if there's your programm. It takes the first matching program and executes it, so in your case the directory `/Library/Frameworks/.../3.6/bin` is before the directory `usr/local/bin`, which means that the `python3` from `/Library/Frameworks/.../3.6/bin` will be used.

You need therefore to change this PATH variable:

```
export PATH="/Users/sky/Documents/software/Montage-master/bin:/usr/share/file/magic/mercurial:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin"
```

You can put that into your `~/.bash_profile` so that it is permanent, and you don't need to set it every time you open a new terminal window.

**Note** that this will not automatically update your path for the remainder of the session. To do this, you should run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure have python3.7 intalled? 
you can view the folder

```
cd /usr/bin
```

Next you search the python's file:

```
find /usr/bin/ python3
```

if don´t exist filename python3.7 install

```
sudo apt install python3.7
sudo apt update
```